# Update nested array and populate before that with mongoose

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to add a photo into a country in mongoose. But country is an array and photo too. Here is my user schema :

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    birthDate: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    sex: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    countries: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Country',
            photos: [
                {
                    base64: {
                        type: String,
                        required: true       
                    },
                    title: String,
                    description: String
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    admin: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
});
```

Here is what I got as data into mongoDB :

[image]

The problem is that I only got the id of countries. And I would like to use another field of the document country. Populate works well when I want to get data, but how to populate and then use the fields to update with mongoDB?

Moreover, I don't know how to update data into nested array, I tried :

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        "name": "CHARLAT",
        "countries": "5d2d847b06f2f94118a36518"
    },
    { $push : { "countries.photos" : {
        base64: "bla"
    } }}
)
```

As you can see, I use a hand written id for country... I could do a find query before on country but can we use populate here?

And I got this in Postman :

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the type is `ObjectId`, it can't have a `photos` field, since it's just an `_id`. It is a reference to another collection.

**Updated answer after comments :**

The best thing to do IMO is to create a `Photo` model which would have the file path and the country's _id. The User model would only store a list of Photos [_id].

**UserSchema :**

```
{
   .....
   photos : [{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Photo'
    }],
   .....
}
```

**PhotoSchema :**

```
{
    country : {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Country'
    },
    path : String
}
```

Then, query your Users this way, by populating the photos, and inside each photo, populating the countries :

```
UserModel
        .find(conditions)
        .populate({ 
             path: 'photos',
             model: 'Photo'
             populate: {
                 path: 'country',
                 model: 'Country'
            } 
         })
         .lean() // Faster and lighter for read-only, simply returns an object
```

So you should get a User object like this :

```
{
    .....
    name : "John",
    photos : [{
         country : {
              name : "Country 1",
              code : "C1" // or whatever field you have in your Country model
         },
         path: "path/to/photo1.jpg"
    },
    {
         country : {
              name : "Country 2",
              code : "C2"
         },
         path: "path/to/photo2.jpg"
    }]
    .....
}
```

Comment: But, the photos are related to a user. A user have visited a country and took some photos. That is why the schema is built like this. Then how could I say that these photos were taken by this user in this country?

Comment: Ah, in that case, the logic is different from my answer, so the model has to be different too. IMO the most logical thing to do is to have a `Photos` model that records their `country` (country's _id). Then, in the `User` model, simply store a list of photos _id. Populate the photos, and if need be, also populate the countries inside the photos (recursive population, Mongoose can do this).

Comment: I have some trouble to understand mongo's logical. So in my document : photos, I won't get the user who took it... Are you sure that you can't add photos into countries into user? I read documentation about this..

Comment: I could also add a Photo model, which store userID, countryID, and photo URL. What do you think is the best? Thank you.

Comment: Yes that's pretty much what I suggested in my comment above :) I think it's a good idea.

Comment: Answer changed to reflect the discussion.

Comment: Just one last thing. If I want to add a photo into country which code is C2, how can I do when I only got the country Id in photoSchema? Can I populate before pushing new data? Or should I first get the correct ID for this country code with find and then update when I got it?

Comment: With this schema, you don't add a photo in the country. You store the country _id in the photo, that's the opposite. And you store photos _id in the User schema. If you really want to store photos in countries, you must change your schemas to reflect that.